# how do I find all records without an associated has_many record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Customers and Customers has_many Properties. I want to find all Customers without a certain property, based on the 'name' of the property.

So, most Customers have a property like so:

```
property.name == 'name'
property.value == 'value'
```

Also, I need to make sure the customer **doesn't** have another property with a different name and value.

I want to find all customers without a specific property and add that property to them. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can find customers without certain property:

```
# assuming property_name is the name of that property that should not exist
customers_without_property = Customer.joins(:properties).where('properties.name != ?', property_name)
```

You can create that property for the found records afterwards like that:

```
customers_without_property.each{|cust| Property.create(customer_id: cust.id, name: property_name, value: property_value}
```